# jQuery UI Cancel a slide animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

So I have this code ..

```
$('.hover-img').hover(function(e) {
    $(this).show("slide", { direction : "left" }, 500);
});

$('.hover-img').mouseleave(function(e) {
    $(this).stop(true, true).hide("slide", { direction : "left" }, 500);
});
```

When the users mouse leaves the image before the slide animation has finished completing, I just want it to stop and go back the other way. This is how I would usually do it but it doesn't seem to work when using jQuery UI slide effect.

Why isn't it working? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have error in your .hide syntax. 
http://api.jquery.com/hide/
It can not have args (string, object, int).

Answer (score 0):

try using...

```
.stop(true, false)
```

To ensure that the animation doesn't snap to the end before reversing. You should also use $.stop() in your hover handler too.

```
$('.hover-img').hover(function(e) {
    $(this).stop(true, false).show(...);
});

$('.hover-img').mouseleave(function(e) {
    $(this).stop(true, false).hide(...);
});
```

Also, see this JSFiddle for an example that uses $.stop() with $.animate() http://jsfiddle.net/fjVDy/1/